# Astropy Tables: set data type from another table

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, astropy

I have one `astropy.Table`, call it `T`:

```
  a      b     c      d
int32 float64 str1 float64
----- ------- ---- -------
    1     2.0    0    10.0
    4     5.0    1    20.0
    5     8.5    2    30.0
```

I want to create another table from a numpy array, but with the same columns and data types as `T`

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

I can create a table with the same column names

```
S = Table(A, names=T.colnames)
```

But if I try to pass the data types as well

```
S = Table(A, names=T.colnames, dtype=T.dtype)
```

then I get an error `ValueError: dtype must be a list or None`, and `list(T.dtype)` just returns `TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not iterable`

How can I pass the data types from one table to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the current release of astropy:

```
Table(A, names=T.colnames, dtype=[T[name].dtype for name in T.colnames])
```

This is already improved in the master branch of astropy and in the next release version 4.2 of astropy you can do simply:

```
Table(A, dtype=T.dtype)
```